# Can't install setuptools for python

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, egg

I'm trying to install setuptools so I can then install html5lib using easy_install, but I'm getting an error that I thought I would be able to fix with the following command:

```
sudo pip --no-cache-dir install -U setuptools
```

However, I'm still getting this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-lULj2T-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pyparsing-2.0.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Comment: `sudo pip --no-cache-dir install --user -U setuptools`

Comment: That worked, thanks! How did adding --user help?

Comment: "The purpose of sudo is to execute a command as another user. The -u or --user option for sudo specifies that user. You're not logging in as that user, just running a command. sudo takes your password to verify your identity for performing such a task."